# randomize char output to text file

Tags: c++, out

I am pretty new to programming in C++, I want to display

How to display produce a output.txt file in this format.

> A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X
>   Y  Z
>
> T W G X Z R L L N H A I A F L E W G Q H V R N V D U

in text file but i am not sure why they display as rubbish.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std;


void random (std::ostream& output)
{
     int letter[26];
     int i,j,temp;

    srand(time(NULL));


        for(i=0; i<26; i++)
            {
                 letter[i] = i+1;
                 output<<(char)(letter[i]+'A'-1)<<" "; 
//by ending endl here i am able to display but the letter will display in horizontal which is not what i wanted     

            }    

        for(i=0; i<26; i++)
        {
            j=(rand()%25)+1; 
            temp = letter[i];
            letter[i] = letter[j];
            letter[j] = temp;
             output<<((char) (letter[i]+'A'-1))<<" ";
        }



}
```

Comment: How to display produce a output.txt file in this format.
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

Comment: No, not Caesar cipher. The first line should be cleartext, the 2nd line should be 26 characters, chosen randomly with replacement.

Comment: If my answer underneath helped, please mark it to let other people know that problem is solved.

Comment: As an aside, you appear to be assuming that 'Z' == 'A' - 1 + 26.  This is not guaranteed, and there are machines running C++ today for which it is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void random (std::ostream& output)
{
     int letter[26];
     int i,j,temp;

    srand(time(NULL));


        for(i=0; i<26; i++)
        {
             letter[i] = i+1;
             output<<(char)(letter[i]+'A'-1)<<" ";      

        }    
        output << "\n";        //that's all what you need
        for(i=0; i<26; i++)
        {
            j=(rand()%25)+1; 
            temp = letter[i];
            letter[i] = letter[j];
            letter[j] = temp;
             output<<((char) (letter[i]+'A'-1))<<" ";
        }



}
```

For the future - don't use std::endl because it also flush stream buffer, which might be unwanted. Use '\n' instead. But whole function can be much simpler:

```
void random (std::ostream& output)
{
    srand(time(NULL));


        for(int i = 65; i < 91; ++i)            // i == 65, because it's A in ASCII
            output << (char)i << " ";
        output << "\n";        //that's all what you need

        for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
        {
             output <<((char)(rand()%26 + 65))<<" ";
        }
}
```

Comment: The 2nd code snippet can not ensure that each character appears exactly once.

Comment: But it doesn't have to. Check out the example - A is two times.

Comment: You need a \n after the second line too.  I'd also prefer to use `' '` and `'\n'` to output a single character, rather than output a string.